# Stop Rewrite htaccess create random pages

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Recently I saw in my webmaster tools that some random sites are linking to my site. Actually this is not a big issue. The issue comes when the pages that are linked are not real pages because of my `.htaccess` file.

This is the `.htaccess` code that I'm running:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So the real URLs would be:

```
mysite.com/folder/999/TITLE-OR-NAME
```

But because I only check the 1st folder `$1` which is a numeric ID, this `.htaccess` file is allowing hackers to link to my site with random URLs like:

```
mysite.com/folder/999/TITLE-OR-NAME1
mysite.com/folder/999/TITLE-OR-NAME2
mysite.com/folder/999/TITLE-OR-NAME3
mysite.com/folder/999/TITLE-OR-NAME4
mysite.com/folder/999/TITLE-OR-NAME5
```

The worst part comes when google tells me that I am duplicating content!!!

Actually I am not duplicating content, the `.htaccess` is duplicating it for me. And yes I know, I'm a bad newbie programmer but I'd really appreciate your help with this 'cause I'm struggling to find a solution but it never works.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tweak this a bit but should get you close:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z]*)([0-9]*)$ [R=404,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The R=404 is saying throw a 404 if they hit this case and don't execeute any more rewrite commands (L). NC means case insensitive.

**EDITED FOR FIXED URLS:**
This will go to each fixed page and all not listed will go to 404. In other words it will check against foo, then against bar, and so on until it hits the end case; a non valid url and then 404's it.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(FOO){1}$ index.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(BAR){1}$ index.php?id=$2 [L]
...
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: As a side note I believe google now allows you to remove bad backlinks to your site.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser Shawn, it is not working because I explained this issue not that good. The title could be not only TITLE-OR-NAME1 or TITLE-OR-NAME2, but TITLE-NAME-GOOD or TITLE-NAME-GOOD-GOOD, so your rule is not working because of this.

Comment: Thanks Shawn but Im looking for a real solution :)

Comment: It becomes impossible to give a solution unless you have something concrete about your data. For example, If we knew that your Name/Title was always the same length or always ended with say 1 digit, then we could stop all other cases easily. If your name/title varies in a variety of ways then there is nothing unique we can decipher with regex. If you do name_01 and title_01 then we can tell the regex to 404 any urls with anything exactly after 2 digits. For example we could 404 name_01asdsad OR name_019, etc.

Comment: OK is there any possibility to make a list in htaccess to permit only the URLs that I want to be shown?